# How to interpret this combinatorics and combination meaning

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, extremal-combinatorics

Given two sequence of strings, one with $n$ elements the other with $m$ elements and $m\geq n$.

We are interesting to align those two sequence, and select $k$ out of $m$ and $n$ respectively for matching, and incorporate with another operations "inserting gap"
E.g( following is one of possible alignment select $3$ out of $7$ and $3$ out of $6$)

$$123-x_1x_2x_3-x_4-$$

$$123y_1---y_2-y_3$$

Below is another possible alignment select $3$ out of $7$, $3$ out of $6$ and  with different inserting gap$$123x_1--x_2-x_3x_4$$

$$123-y_1y_2-y_3--$$

The lecturer gives a inequality as follows $$\text{Total possible number of alignment}\ >\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {m\choose k}{n\choose k} $$

Can any one tell me the interpretation of ${m\choose k}{n\choose k}$, I don't see the meaning of number of ways to select $k$ in $m$ multiply the number of ways to select $k$ in $n$.

Any comments will be appreciated

Comment: I find the details of the question unclear, especially how the elements not chosen are dealt with, but it seems that the idea is as follows. In your first string, choose k of the n elements arbitrarily. In your second string, choose k of the m elements arbitrarily. Align the two so that the chosen elements of the first string are all left of the chosen elements of the right string. This yields $\binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k}$ different alignments, for each k. Clearly we can do better than having all to the left or right, so the inequality is strict. These are related to "shuffles".

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Sorry, I don't see how is that yield ${n\choose k}{m\choose k}$ alignment

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I think this problem can be rethink of as follow, if the elements are not chosen, the number of ways to sert the not chosen elements from string A into not chosen elements in string B

Comment: I'm sorry, there seem to be significant language barriers here, I don't really know what you're trying to say.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson My bad. You said it's unclear with how the not chosen elements are dealt with. Maybe could think in this way. look at above example, we insert $y_1,y_2,y_3$ into $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, but order in each $y$ or $x$ has to preserve. How many ways to have such insertion= total number of possible alignment

Answer (score 1):

I'm now thinking you're asking about the number of ways to shuffle a string $s$ of length $m$ and a string $t$ of length $n$, assuming all letters are distinct. This is just $\binom{n+m}{m}$: for the $n+m$ locations in the combined word, choose $m$ of them to come from the first word (with the rest coming from the second word). It turns out
$$\binom{n+m}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\min\{n, m\}} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k}.$$
(You wrote > instead of = apparently in error?)

This is a special case of the Vandermonde convolution identity and can be proven using any of the usual techniques. You can for instance let $k$ be the number of letters coming from the first string $s$ among the first $m$ positions of the combined word.